# twitter and facebook connect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, restful-authentication

Excuse I need a tutorial for twitter and facebook connect.

The user can register in my site or enter through twitter or facebook login access data

How i could implement this functionality if I am using rails 2.3.8 and RESTful authentication?

I need the model for database (how save this information and its relationships) and implement in my page.

Example: http://www.myntmarket.com/

I find a tutorial with restful authentication and facebooker but facebooker is deprecated. So i find facebooker2. somebody could explain me how can i use this plugin.

Thanks in advance and excuse me my syntax in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Twitter but look up Facebooker.

What database model? If you connect with facebook you don't need their models. You could store their user credentials if it is not against the Facebook API TOS and you don't need their models to do so.

Comment: OK But do i need save some information?. Also i need a tutorial of facebooker2 and restfl authetication. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to stay with Rails 2? Otherwise, Omniauth and Rails 3 would be an option, I have a fully functional demo on Github: https://github.com/markusproske/omniauth_pure

Comment: Yes, i need to use rails 2.3.8 for this project. The next project i megrate to Rails 3